# image upload without registration in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, registration, image-uploading

I am creating a classified website for my client. Client need ads to be post without registration of a user. I am complete that task but the problem is that user is not able to Ad images in media library. Please help me out or suggest me any possible solution.

I have tried all the suggestion on https://themeskills.com/fix-http-error-when-uploading-images-to-wordpress/ 
but this solution doesn't help me.

Comment: Do you know it could be risky and a way for hackers. and If you still want to provide this feature then create a simple PHP form for Media uploading. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

with these plugins can do what you are trying to do:

**DJD Site Post**
[image: DJD Site Post in action]
https://wordpress.org/plugins/djd-site-post/

**Frontend Uploader,**
[image: Frontend Uploader]
https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/